# Find the derivative of the function $F(x) = \int_{\tan{x}}^{x^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+t^4}}\,dt$.

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{align}
\left(\int_{\tan{x}}^{x^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+t^4}}\,dt\right)' &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+t^4}}2x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+t^4}}\sec^2{x} \\
&= \frac{2x}{\sqrt{2+t^4}} - \frac{\sec^2{x}}{\sqrt{2+t^4}} \\
&= \frac{2x-\sec^2{x}}{\sqrt{2+t^4}} \\
\end{align}$$

**Update:**

Is this looking better??

$$\begin{align}
\left(\int_{\tan{x}}^{x^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+t^4}}\,dt\right)' &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+(x^2)^4}}2x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+(\tan{x})^4}}\sec^2{x} \\
&= \frac{2x}{\sqrt{2+x^8}} - \frac{\sec^2{x}}{\sqrt{2+\tan^4{x}}} \\
\end{align}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: It seems like you don't have any clue what integration is...

Comment: Your answer is indeed far from correct..... Can you explain to us how you get, for example, the first equality?

Comment: You probably mean differentiate.  Then you must replace $t$ by $x^2$ in the first part and by $\tan x$ in the second part.

Comment: No, and I suggest you to try to compute something simpler, like $\int_0^x t\,dt$ (the same principle), if you don't know how to do...

Comment: I originally had "integrate" when that was incorrect, I edited to to read "Find the derivative".

Comment: @avid19 How on Earth is that constructive in any way?

Comment: Yikes you guys are mean

Comment: Sorry for asking...

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you for the help.  That is what I meant.  I was confusing the two.

Comment: and thanks @alexqwx :)  I thought the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

$\text{ Recall } \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t) dt=F(b(x))-F(a(x)) \text{ *note:} \text{( where } F'=f) \\ \frac{d}{dx}[F(b(x))-F(a(x))]=\frac{d}{dx}F(b(x))-\frac{d}{dx}F(a(x)) \text{ by difference rule } \\ \\ \text{ now you use chain rule and you are almost there } $

Comment: You should use dummy variables, for example $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(y) dy$. The integration variable doesn't "exist" outside of the integration scope.

Comment: Yeah I usually do but I'm typing around a cat :p and thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Hint to find derivative: Use FTC, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements, $F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int^x_a f(t)dt=f(x)$

Answer to original question: HINT to integrate: \begin{align}
\int_{\tan{x}}^{x^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+t^4}}\,dt &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \int_{\tan{x}}^{x^2}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{t^4}{2}}}\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \int_{\tan{x}}^{x^2}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{t^4}{2}}}\,dt \\
\end{align}
Then let $\tan^2 u=t^4/2$

Answer (score 0):

No. $t$ is a mute variable. The answer must have $x$ as the only variable. Yor computations are similar to
$$
\int_1^2t\,dt=2\cdot t-1\cdot t=t,
$$
which is obviously wrong.